# How to break line in REXX

Tags: line, new-operator, break, rexx

Can anyone tell me how to break line in rexx language.
E.g: 
say "ala has a cat"0D0A"Cat has a ala"

in result I would like have: 
ala has a cat
Cat has a ala

I want to post data to a pushgateway server and the syntax requires enter at the end of the line

Answer (score 2):

Hex 0D0A is a carriage return new line so if you add that to the end of your string it will look like an "enter". If you don't need the new line just remove the 0A from the CRLF variable.

```
CRLF = "0D0A"x
say "ala has a cat Cat has a ala" CRLF
```

If you need each line separately use

```
CRLF = "0D0A"x
say "ala has a cat" CRLF "Cat has a ala" CRLF
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but in my environment it does not work: 

/* REXX */                                   
CRLF = "0D0A"x                               
say "ala has a cat" CRLF "Cat has a ala" CRLF
I have output: 
IKT00405I SCREEN ERASURE CAUSED BY ERROR RECOVERY PROCEDURE
***  do you know why this can happen?

Comment: Not a clue but what is your environment?

Comment: z/OS 5.2 on Mainframe z13

Comment: You're working in TSO on z/OS.  Your data is almost certainly encoded in EBCDIC, not ASCII.

Answer (score -2):

In z/os  REXX you can
a = "good" ,                 /* skip to next line */
"morning"